# Google PostMaster Service with PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-postmaster

I am new to Google Sevices.I am trying to setup and use
**Gmail Postmaster Tools API**

https://developers.google.com/gmail/postmaster/reference/rest

I am able to use it with PostMan but I want use it with PHP. So I have setup client and using something like this

```
$service = new \Google\Service\PostmasterTools($client);
$results = $service->domains->listDomains();
```

Its working fine and providing me domain list. but I do not have idea how I can get trafficStats for the domain

```
https://developers.google.com/gmail/postmaster/reference/rest/v1/domains.trafficStats/get
```

I have searched lot but not found any tutorial or example related PostMaster tool in PHP.

Let me know if any expert here can help me for the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just randomly came across this and see it's unanswered -- you probably figured it out by now but you could iterate over $results and call listDomainsTrafficStats()

ex)

```
foreach($results->domains as $domain){
  $stats = $service->domains_trafficStats->listDomainsTrafficStats($domain->name);
}
```